# Spring Cloud Stream + Kafka Stream - KStream not consuming message from the topic

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

Trying our a sample project using **Spring Cloud Stream + Kafka Stream** but the Messages published to the input topic/queue are not consumed by the Processor method (**KStream** as argument).

**Binding Definition**

```
public interface WordCountChannelBindings {

    // Channel to PUBLISH and FETCH 'words'
    String _wordsOutput = "words_output_channel";
    String _wordsInput = "words_input_channel";

    // Channel to PUBLISH and FETCH 'words-count' details
    String _countOutput = "counts_output_channel";
    String _countInput = "counts_input_channel";

    // Source
    @Output(_wordsOutput)
    MessageChannel _wordsOutput();

    // Sink
    @Input(_wordsInput)
    KStream<String, PageViewEvent> _wordsInput();

    // Source
    @Output(_countOutput)
    KStream<String, Long> _countOutput();

    // Sink
    @Input(_countInput)
    KTable<String, Long> _countInput();
}
```

**Producer**

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
public void wordsProducer() {
        List<String> names = Arrays.asList("mfisher", "dyser", "schacko", "abilan", "ozhurakousky", "grussell");
        List<String> pages = Arrays.asList("blog", "sitemap", "initializr", "news", "colophon", "about");

        String rPage = pages.get(new Random().nextInt(pages.size()));
        String rName = pages.get(new Random().nextInt(names.size()));
        PageViewEvent pageViewEvent = new PageViewEvent(rName, rPage, Math.random() > .5 ? 10 : 1000);

        // Publish the words into the OUTPUT Topic
        this.wordCountChannelBindings._wordsOutput().send(
                MessageBuilder.withPayload(pageViewEvent)
                        .build());

        log.info("Words published - {}", pageViewEvent);
    }
```

**Processor**

```
@Component
public class WordsStreamProcessor {

    @StreamListener
    @SendTo(WordCountChannelBindings._countOutput)
    public KStream<String, Long> process(@Input(WordCountChannelBindings._wordsInput) KStream<String, PageViewEvent> input) {
        log.info("Process data - {}", input);
        return input.filter((key, value) -> value.getDuration() > 10)
                .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(value.getPage(), "0"))
                .groupByKey()
                .count(Materialized.as("wordscount"))
                .toStream();
    }

}
```

**Consumer**

```
 @StreamListener
    public void wordsCountConsumer(@Input(WordCountChannelBindings._countInput) KTable<String, Long> wordsCountDetails) {
        log.info("Consumed Result - {}", wordsCountDetails);
    }
```

**SB Main class**

```
@EnableScheduling
@EnableBinding(WordCountChannelBindings.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringCloudStreamKafkaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringCloudStreamKafkaApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**application.yml**

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder:
  brokers:
    - localhost:9092

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder:
  applicationId: word-count-sample
  configuration:
    commit.interval.ms: 100
    default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
    default.value.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.words_output_channel:
  destination: words_topic
  producer:
    headerMode: none

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.words_input_channel:
  destination: words_topic
  consumer:
    headerMode: none

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.counts_output_channel:
  destination: counts_topic
  producer:
    useNativeEncoding: true

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.counts_input_channel:
  destination: counts_topic
  consumer:
    useNativeDecoding: true
    headerMode: none
  group: wordscount
  contentType: application/json

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.counts_output_channel:
  producer:
    keySerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
    valueSerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$LongSerde

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.counts_input_channel:
  consumer:
    keySerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
    valueSerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$LongSerde
```

**Logs**

```
2020-07-17 12:31:45.893  INFO 17236 --- [ask-scheduler-4] l.k.s.s.c.stream.producer.WordsProducer  : Words published - PageViewEvent(userId=about, page=colophon, duration=1000)
2020-07-17 12:31:46.895  INFO 17236 --- [ask-scheduler-8] l.k.s.s.c.stream.producer.WordsProducer  : Words published - PageViewEvent(userId=initializr, page=blog, duration=10)
2020-07-17 12:31:47.899  INFO 17236 --- [ask-scheduler-3] l.k.s.s.c.stream.producer.WordsProducer  : Words published - PageViewEvent(userId=blog, page=news, duration=1000)
2020-07-17 12:31:48.900  INFO 17236 --- [ask-scheduler-9] l.k.s.s.c.stream.producer.WordsProducer  : Words published - PageViewEvent(userId=sitemap, page=about, duration=10)
```

As shown in the above logs the **PageViewEvent** is published to the topic every second but the **Processor method** which supposed to transform the event is not consuming the messages. No error seen in the log.

Kindly help to get this working.

Initially tried with

```
<spring-cloud.version>Hoxton</spring-cloud.version>
<version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
```

and also with

```
<spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
<version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
```

But facing the same issue.

Comment: I just tried your code and it is working fine for me. Can you provide a small reproducible application? That way, we can triage it further to troubleshoot.

Comment: @sobychacko Thank you for looking into this - I've commited the Spring Boot App into https://github.com/rajay2r/spring-cloud-stream-kafka-stream

Also, added the application-log generated.

Comment: Observed these in the logs - not sure these are normal behavior
2020-07-19 08:32:50.018  INFO 12312 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=word-count-sample-8b482882-c246-42fe-aab9-23258ef5c666-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=word-count-sample] Setting newly assigned partitions [word-count-sample-wordscount-repartition-0, words_topic-0]